# Инсталлер для Qt-приложения

Tags: qt

Здравствуйте. Что-то сходу ничего не нашел, поэтому спрошу здесь.
Есть ли какая утилитка, которая сделает проект Qt (exe + необходимые dll) инсталлятором со стандартными настройками (путь, запуск после установки и пр.)?

UPD: Все необходимые файлики я ей сам скормлю, т.е. дело даже не в Qt, а в том как из набора exe+dll's получить не архив, а привычный пользователю установщик? Должны же быть где-то такие. Я думаю всякие "репакеры" программ и софта ими пользуются.

Comment: Нет такой программы, я во всяком случае ни разу не слышал. И либы всегда только ручками тянуть, можно пользоваться сторонними утилитами, что бы выяснить, каких либ не хватает, ибо бывает так, что прога просто вылетает с ошибкой без указания что за библиотека, лично я пользовался Process Monitor (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645)

Comment: @MorkOFF48, да вроде как-то народ делает всякие репаки программ и другого софта. Не пишут же они под них инсталляторы)

Comment: @Андрей Бакша, делают, но точно не на Qt

Comment: @progzdeveloper, похоже это то, что нужно) Просто никогда раньше этим не занимался и не знал в какую сторону копать.  
Спасибо. Преобразуйте комментарий в ответ - помечу как правильный.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Видимо Вам установщик нужно сделать: посмотрите в сторону NSIS -  http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nullsoft_Scriptable_Install_System

Answer (score 4):

Qt сразу поставляется с такой утилитой. Вот подробная [статья](https://habrahabr.ru/post/262211/) о том, как ею пользоваться.

Answer (score 0):

Ни в коем случае не стоит юзать встроенный создатель установщиков. Используй Smart Install Maker, он с графическим интерфейсом и удобнее. Ключ активации лежит на ответы@mail.ru уже давно, так что он бесплатный

Answer (score 0):

Есть Qt Installer Framework, сам сейчас с ним разбираюсь, и вроде как в нем есть все что Вы описали. Это если хочется, чтобы именно на qt было, а так куча всяких инсталлеров имеется, платных и бесплатных.

Answer (score 0):

Я использую Inno Script Studio в связке с Inno Setup. Очень удобный и понятный инструмент для создания инсталляторов. В сети можно найти много примеров использования. А по сути один раз написал скрипт для своей программы, для других его же и используешь. Для Qt нужно будет самому указать необходимые dll для вашего exe